# Page Load Wait and Keys codes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone tell me how to type text and press enter key in browser address bar in selenium webdriver?﻿ I am using C# bindings.

and

Please explain how can I make webdriver to wait untill the new webpage fully loaded in browser.

Comment: I think it's much more easier to look for a beginner documentation than creating an account on SO to ask something without any try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium cannot input the  URL in browser address bar, if you want to open a website, please use below code to open the page:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Ok and can you please tell me about page load. I mean how can I wait for complete pageload after clicking on Signin button ?

Comment: @JawadK. you can use webdriverwait, for example, on the loading page, there is a element A, you can use below code to wait page loading complete `Webdriverwait.until(ExpectedConditions(ElementIsClickable(A)))` please refer to the link [How to use WebdriverWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to see how to use webdriverwait

Comment: thank you sooooo much .... I have change the condition for my scenario and its works great.... !!!!! : ) 

`
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.wdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
            IWebElement elem = Browser.wdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[1]/tq-app/div[2]/div/task-listing/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button"));
`